# Regex for validating email and add dot symbol

Tags: php, validation

Everybody, I need To allow just string and numbers and dots "." in my email

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users|not_regex:/^.+$/i|regex :/^.+@.+$/i',
```

My Code Here is not allowing for "." i ned to allow just "." and block others like 
[# / \ $%^&* etc]

Comment: Why not just allow all possible emails? Regex is not the correct tool.

Comment: @Andreas i have done that but i need to block some things like  / and #  So all i need to do to accept just numbers and text and dots in my email

Comment: If you done it correctly then there shouldn't be a need for regex. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need a regex nowadays to validate a string consisting of an email address that should only include  letters, numbers, and the @ and dot symbols.  PHP allows for proper validation when you apply [filter_var()](http://php.net/filter_var) twice, first to sanitize the data and then again to validate it, as follows:

```
<?php
// Variables to check
$emailA = "john1.doe@example.com";
$emailB = "john1.doe@example#.com";

// Remove all illegal characters from email
$emailValid = filter_var($emailA, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$emailInvalid = filter_var($emailB, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

// Validate e-mail
if (filter_var($emailValid, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo("$emailValid is a valid email address"),"\n";
} else {
    echo("$emailValid is not a valid email address");
}
if (filter_var($emailInvalid, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo("$emailInvalid is a valid email address");
} else {
    echo("$emailInvalid is not a valid email address");
}
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/rHeLo)

Note, if this code seems familiar, I admit that I modified the example given [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_var.asp) :)

However if you insist on using a regex, here is one way to do so:

```
<?php

$emailA = "john1@here.com";
$emailB = "john1@here#.com";

function validateEmail( $email ){
$regex =  "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/";
$error =   "\nOnly letters, numbers, dot and @ are allowed"; 

echo (preg_match($regex,$email))?  "$email is valid\n" : "$error - $email is invalid\n";

return true;
}

validateEmail( $emailA );
validateEmail( $emailB );
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/l4jc8#output)

It might seem kind of odd to have validateEmail() return true whether an email is valid or invalid.  The return value can be useful if you need to verify that this function actually executed; see example [here](https://3v4l.org/CI5kn#output).

Comment: Thanks So Much For your Answer, you helped me saved my life